# AWS ubuntu 16.04, permission denied, error code when trying to edit, upload through winScp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can see my files but not able to edit or delete. How to get permission. Any command?? I want to get root access

Comment: please share the console o/p of your command.

Comment: what os you are using Linux or windows  ?

Answer (score 0):

you can winscp to /tmp to which all users has access...

to get root access while doing ssh just type following
$sudo su -